# Determine the most frequent value for an attribute based on another attribute

Tags: fields-attributes, frequency

I need to determine the most frequent value of one attribute based on another.

For example:

```
Field 1     Field 2
Cat         Tabby
Cat         White
Cat         White
Dog         Brown
Dog         Brown
Dog         Brown
Dog         White
Dog         White
Bird        Yellow
```

would return:

```
Field 1     Field 2
Cat         White
Dog         Brown
Bird        Yellow
```

I know I can use the summary statistics to get a frequency count, but I need a way to return the value that occurs the most frequently, not the number of times it occurs.

Comment: Are you looking for some sort of automated technique that would save this elsewhere? If so, please update with the code that you've tried.

Comment: what software are you using?

Comment: Concatenate both, define frequency. Split in 2 columns, sort descending, remove duplicate.